TV series about small software company
I am trying to identify an old TV show with the following properties:

Was broadcast in the 1990s or 2000s in Egypt, but the show likely came from the United States
it is about a man who started a software company and gathered a team of programmers to work in small place in his hometown
A product they developed is an antivirus called PC Cop or something like that
the main character has a brother who doesn't work in software, but falls in love with a female programmer working with his brother.  In one scene she invites him to her place to use his voice in a voice recognition program.


The show that you are looking for is Hyperion Bay. 

The series centers around Dennis Sweeney (Mark-Paul Gosselaar) who, after a successful career in the software business, returns home to open a local division for the company he works for. The series follows the drama when the new meets the old in the little coastal town of Hyperion Bay, California.

(I was looking for it myself on Google and found this site. Remembered the name of one actor that's how I found it.)

This sounds like the same series which was answered in this question. The answer there was Dweebs.
Here is the write-up:

Warren ( Peter Scolari), was a young computer software writer whose programs had made him a legend in the industry. Unfortunately, he was painfully shy and socially maladjusted as well as eccentric ( to come up with ideas for the next " killer app," he bounced on a trampoline in his office). His Seattle company, Cyberbite, was staffed with 3 talented but similarly socially inept programmers. Karl ( Stephen Tobolowsky), the oldest dressed horribly; Vic ( Corey Feldman), who thought his dark glasses made him cool was constantly depressed; and Morley ( David Kaufman), who had been Vic's buddy since high school, was allergic to everything-especially women. Into their dysfunctional world came Carey ( Farrah Forke), the sexy new office manager who knew absolutely nothing about computers but much about life. She hired Todd (Adam Biesk), as a gofer who among other things , translated technospeak into English for her, and set out to give them real lives and some style. Despite their eccentricities, they were nice guys-they just needed help dealing with the outside world.


thanks for the answer but its not the show , Dweebs is a comedy series and the series that i mention is not a comedy

Fair enough ... I'm sure the answer will pop!
